# Matching loudness of commentary track with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFmpeg to mix a MP3 file containing a commentary track into the soundtrack of multimedia file. So far I have had great success using FFmpeg's [`sidechaincompress` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sidechaincompress) to [auto-duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ducking) the soundtrack stream before mixing in the commentary. You can hear the commentary clearly, even when there's loud music or explosions going on in the film.

Awesome.

However, the issue I have now is during the very quiet scenes. When the soundtrack is very quiet, the commentary *seems* far too loud. If I adjust the volume of the entire commentary track so that it sounds right during the quiet scenes, it's too heard to hear during the loud scenes.

My current idea is to somehow use the `sidechaincompress` filter to duck the commentary track as well, before finally mixing it into the soundtrack. The problem though is that `sidechaincompress` compresses the target's volume when the source is loud, but I need the volume to be compressed when the source is quiet.

I have to admit that I am a quiet the newbie in this domain, so I may coming at this entirely wrong. I'm happy for any advice you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into a similar problem recently and it seems like [`sidechaincompress`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sidechaincompress) does exactly what we need in this situation.
I used the following command to merge commentary[0:2] track with main track[0:1]

```
ffmpeg -i "multi-audio-track-source.mkv" -filter_complex "\
    [0:1]aformat=sample_fmts=s16:channel_layouts=stereo[main];\         # these eliminate warnings about mismatching tracks.
    [0:2]aformat=sample_fmts=s16:channel_layouts=stereo[commentarytmp];\   # these eliminate warnings about mismatching tracks.
    [commentarytmp]asplit=2[commentarycmpr][commentary];\                  # same connecting pin cannot be used in 2 filters so we have to make a copy of the commentary audio track for later mixing.
    [main][commentarycmpr]sidechaincompress[cmpr]; \        
    [cmpr][commentary]amix[final]" \ 
 -map "0:0" -map "[final]" \
 -c:v copy -c:a aac single-audio-track-output.mkv
```